# How to calculate $G(0),G'(0),G''(0)$ from $G(x)=\int^0_x g(t)dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

How to calculate $G(0),G'(0),G''(0)$ from $G(x)=\int^0_x g(t)dt$?

I think $G(0)=\int^0_0 g(t)dt$ is just a single point so $G(0)=0$

Also since $G(x)=-\int^x_0 g(t)dt$, so $G'(0)=-g(0)$ and $G''(0)=-g(0)$.

Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

We assume $g$ is differentiable near $0$. You rather have
$$
G''(0)=-g'(0)
$$ the rest is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$G(x)=-\int_0^x g(t)\, dt$$

If $g(x)$ is continuous, then $G'(x)=-g(x)$. Furthermore, if $g$ is differentiable, $G''(x)=-g'(x)$.